# Order won't programmatically mark as completed

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I am struggling to get an order to be marked as completed in Drupal 7 Commerce.

Customers will go through the checkout process inside of Drupal, gets marked as "Awaiting shipment" (a custom order status), but then a fulfillment team goes through a different program and the order should be getting updated programmatically as "Completed".

However, when I use `commerce_order_status_update` it doesn't seem to want to get marked as completed.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
$order_entity = commerce_order_load($orderId); 
commerce_order_status_update($order_entity, 'completed', false, true, 'Order updated via warehouse');
watchdog('warehouse', 'Order status updated %o', array('%o' => $order_entity->status)); //Does not equal 'completed'
```

I know this code is firing because of two reasons:

1. When I set 'completed' to be different status messages, it works
2. I see the revision message "Order updated via warehouse", but the status has not changed.

Is there something I have missed? Am I marking the order as completed in a wrong way?

I have also tried EMW

```
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', commerce_order_load($orderId));
$order_wrapper->status->set('completed');
watchdog('warehouse', 'Order status updated %o', array('%o' => $order_wrapper_status->value())); // Does not update to 'completed'
$order_wrapper->save();
```

**EDIT**
I added the watchdog statements that I have used to echo out of the operation was successful. 
It should also be noted that there are no Rules modifying the order status at this point. I have gone through my list of Rules and verified that nothing is modifying it, and the order history shows no new revision created from Rules.
Error logs also show no error happening on save process. The operation is successful if I change 'completed' to any other status.

Comment: There is rule that fires on order status change. What does it say? You could turn debugging options on in Rules settings to see the log.

Comment: If the status isn't updating as you'd expect, you need to look for one of two things: an error in the save process that prevents the change from being saved to the database or code that executes after that update to set the status back to something else. Without further information, there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: @RyanSzrama You are absolutely right. I have added more information that I hope is useful. I have updated the question to include information about rules and additional debug steps.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this issue out.

I had a Rule that was firing "before a commerce order was saved" that reset the order status but did not show any errors or log any thing. Not sure why that rule wsn't working correctly, but now that I have disabled it, the status is updating successfully.

Comment: hehe, glad to hear it. I should've put my comment in an answer to get the karma. : P